# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongoose, undefined, ejs

Been working on this for 2 weeks straight and can't seem to pass a simple function and variables through to my ejs file. Almost going to give up.

Here's my code below with all requirements.

I've included the app.js file code, the EJS file, and the Embed.js file that has the mongoose Schemas for both User and Comments defined based on the details respectively. Also have included the nesting that works successfully I believe, for comments made by users to be a part of each User's attributes under "comments" which has a an attribute itself as "message" for each message they have.

It's a bit confusing, but that links together well I believe (but could be wrong), so when I run the code, it works fine, but when I go into the database to try and find that users' comments I don't end up seeing it, maybe it's not saving the comments?

Some comments seem to be saved, from how I had the code before while running Create commands with an older version of my code, and then now it seems to run fine as well, but I can't find any of the comments to display, and keeps telling me that the function right before my .forEach command is undefined and has no value.

So sometimes I could get it to run, but it wouldn't display any data from the database, whether it saved from even before, nor now. It seems to save, but can't find the data from the database?

I'm very confused as the log data that shows everytime the code runs, there's a ton of comments that have been made that have been kept on record.

But either way it just tells me it's not defined, so I feel that the data is not referenced properly in the EJS file, and maybe not even done correctly to reference that data in the first place from the app.js file, or possibly in the embed.js file. I'm not sure what to do; tried everything and I feel further from the answer.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
// APP.JS FILE

 // REQUIRE ALL OF THE FILES INSTALLED ON DEPENDENCIES

var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
// var Comment = require('./models/comment.js');
// var User = require('./models/user.js');
var Embed = require('./models/embed');
// const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

var CSSapp = require('./public/stylesheets/app.css');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var User = User;
var Comment = Comment;
var path = require('path');


db.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", error);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/brainstudent', { useNewUrlParser: true });
app.set('views', './brainstudentreal/views');
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/comment", function(req, res) {
    // find all the users and their respective comments
    db.Users.find({}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(user);
            res.render("comment", {user: user});
        }
    })
})


// EJS FILE 

<div>
        <% users.forEach(function(comment) { %>
    <p><%= comment.message %> </p>

        <% }) %>
</div>



// THIS IS THE EMBED.JS FILE WITH COMMENT AND USER DEFINED IN MONGOOSE SCHEMA
// REQUIRE ALL OF THE FILES INSTALLED ON DEPENDENCIES

var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
// var Comment = require('./models/comment.js');
// var User = require('./models/user.js');
// var Embed = require('./models/embed');
// const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');






    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/brainstudent', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    app.set('views', './brainstudentreal/views');
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    var path = require('path');
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


    // define comment in variable before userSchema

    //REQUIRED FROM MODELS FILE COMMENT.JS
    // var Comment = require('./comment.js');

    var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
         message: {type: String}
    });

    var Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
    module.exports = Comment;

    //REQUIRED FROM MODELS FILE USER.JS

    // var User = require('./user');

    // THE MODEL USED FOR COMMENTING FOR USERS respective of each USER
    // var Comment = require('comment');

    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String},
        email: {type: String},
        city: {type: String},
        careertype: {type: String},
        comments: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Comment"
            }

        ]
    });

    var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
    module.exports = User;

Comment.create({
    message: "a new message that I've made! an even NEWER one yo. I guess this will never end.."
}, function(err, comment) {
    User.findOne({name: "Charlie"}, function(err, foundUser) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            foundUser.comments.push(comment);
            foundUser.save(function(err,data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

)

User.findOne({email: "charliebrown@gmail.com"}).populate("comments").exec(function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(user);
    }
})
```

Comment: If the error is _"Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"_, then `db.Users` is `undefined`

Comment: I have no idea about any of the frameworks used here, but your view file has `users` (plural) and you render it with `{user: user}` (singular).

Comment: you have to import you Users and then Users.find() , now you are trying to find users on the connection instance db

Comment: As mentioned by Phil, `db.Users.find` won't work because `db.Users` is `undefined`. If you're using mongoose, then you should be able to import the User model (which it appears you were doing, but it's commented out) `var User = require('./models/user.js');` should then give you the ability to do `User.find()` then change `function(err, user)` to `function(err, users)` and `{user: user}` to `{users}`